# Laravel Get data from Form to Database

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel-5, mamp

I don't understands why but when I try to post my form "entreprise" in my database, all the values are null. 
In the code for the moment I am testing everything with only one data of my form = nomEntreprise.
web.php 
I use two routes : one to return my view and the second one to post my data

```
Route::get('/entreprise/', 'EntrepriseController@index')->name('entreprise');
Route::post('store', 'EntrepriseController@store');
```

EntrepriseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\EntrepriseRequest;
use App\postEntreprise;


class EntrepriseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth/entreprise');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
 public function store(EntrepriseRequest $request)
    {
        $content = [];
        $contact['nomEntreprise'] = $request->post('nomEntreprise');
        var_dump ($request->post());
        return 'test';
    }
```

EntrepriseRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EntrepriseRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nomEntreprise' => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

entreprise.blade.php
I use one template for my form

```
@extends('layouts.form')
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('card')

    @component('components.card')

        <form method="post" action="store">

            {{ csrf_field() }}

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-account',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'nomEntreprise',
                'placeholder' => 'Nom d\'entreprise',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-home',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'address_1',
                'placeholder' => 'Adresse 1',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-home',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'address_2',
                'placeholder' => 'Adresse 2',
                'required' => false,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-home',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'cp',
                'placeholder' => 'Code Postal',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-home',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'ville',
                'placeholder' => 'Ville',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-web',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'www',
                'placeholder' => 'Site Web',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-email',
                'type' => 'email',
                'name' => 'email',
                'placeholder' => 'Email de Contact de L\'entreprise',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-phone-classic',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'telephone_1',
                'placeholder' => 'Téléphone',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-cellphone-android',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'telephone_2',
                'placeholder' => 'Portable',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @include('partials.form-group', [
                'logo' => 'mdi mdi-fax',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'fax',
                'placeholder' => 'Fax',
                'required' => true,
                ])

            @component('components.button')
                @lang('Inscription')
            @endcomponent

        </form>

    @endcomponent

@endsection
```

Comment: what this statement is giving you?  `var_dump ($request->post());`

Comment: array(1) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "kW9ZJJoBP7j0VvthNd8f1O2FS4g8vEl5xIv2d50n" }

Comment: Why do you have a blank validation rule in `EntrepriseRequest`? Get rid of it while you are testing. Also, we can't see all your partials which make up the form.  Check the rendered HTML, does it look OK?  Do all your `input`s have names?